# Apple style transform

Tags: html, css

[Apple Link](http://www.apple.com/iphone/)
I really liked this transform, anybody can give me an idea how they made this animation ?

Comment: I would assume it's all [HTML5](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/48-excellent-html5-demos/)

Comment: Use the source Luke...er...@Extelliquent.

Comment: its not html5.. you can figure it out if you take a look at coding of the page. ;)

Comment: I made a simplified example of what they are doing: http://jsfiddle.net/Yw9SK/2/ Though they are doing it with CSS3 animations/keyframes and chaining events on the animationEnd event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, and a great use of available technology regarding performance and graceful degradation. Here is a [link that outlines it a bit](http://www.bram.us/2011/10/26/apples-iphone-4s-css3-animation-explained/), and a [demo](http://johnbhall.com/iphone-4s/) that gives a bigger look at the sort of technique used.

This doesn't nail it exactly, as there are a few detail transitions excluded, but you probably get the idea from this.

edit: When you see animations like this, they are typically using css3 with javascript as a fallback. Javascript is more widely supported, but a little less efficient to write and lacking gpu acceleration, so it's not as ideal.

Comment: Before I read; I think all it does is that css3 transform puts the element and when you click the jquery css3 sends the item back and another items comes.. I`ll take a look at it thank you!!

Comment: after; He explains the way I thought and its very smart and I`ll try to make something like that and if I can make it I can share it with you guys.